# Problema Cargar imagen gdrive DomPDF laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Hay alguna forma de que al generar el PDF se muestre una imagen guardada que esta en la nube. Me explico:

En la base de datos se registra un textarea con formato(html). Ese campo es el que estoy llamando para que se genere el PDF. todo el texto si me lo convierte correctamente de html a texto normal. Pero, si el usuario adjuntara una imagen eso no lo carga solo muestra un cuadro que no se pudo cargar la imagen.

mi controlador para crear el PDF es el siguiente:

```
     public function crearPDF($id)
 {             
    $data = HistorialMedico::findOrFail($id); 
    $pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])->loadView('pdf.historialMedicoPDF',compact('data'));
     return $pdf->download('Historial-Medico.pdf');
 }
```

Al generar el pdf se muestra de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podría hacer para mostrar la imagen ya que al estar incrustada en un texto en formato enriquecido no tengo control de ello.

EDITADO:
esta es la vista que genera el PDF:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PDF Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    {!! $data->tratamiento !!}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos la vista `pdf.historialMedicoPDF`?

Comment: @L.Flor listo ya edite la publicacion con la vista te agradezco si me puedes ayudar

Comment: Disculpa, pero no veo la parte en donde llamas a la imagen

Comment: @L.Flor es que  como indique la imagen esta guardada dentro de un campo de la base de datos de tipo text que almacena todo lo digitado por el usuario y entre eso puede adjuntar imagenes por medio de la url de google fotos. no es una imagen que yo guarde en el sistema sino que el usuario lo adjunta por medio de la url y todo se almacena en ese campo text

Comment: @L.Flor el campo "tratamiento" contiene todo texto y la imagen.. yo lo que hice en el sistema fue usar CKEDITOR

Comment: Probablemente haya error debido al certificado HTTPS de las imágenes, prueba haciendo esto https://pastebin.com/1WwfwxJH, para deshabilitar el certificado SSL.